# Why does Chrome developer tools computed tab mention the rendered font to be a dot "."?

Tags: fonts, google-chrome-devtools

The question is easy to understand if you see the picture attached:

[image]

As you can see above, the "Rendered Fonts" section of the "Computed" tab on Chrome Developer Tools, refers to the font rendered with a "."

What does that mean?

Note that the Web page is using a "Roboto" font.

Comment: You tell us? It's a font with only 14 glyphs in it, so clearly it's a subset font, what CSS did you use for the element you're inspecting? It doesn't really matter what the entire page is using, since elements can override which font they're using. What does the "styles" section (not the computer section) say about which font family it's using or inheriting?

Comment: The "styles" tab says that the element has the "font-family" "roboto". And the "computed" tab mentions the same. Its the "Rendered Fonts" on "computed" tab that mentions the ".". BTW, the 14 glyphs means that the phrase/text the selected element is of length 14. It's not that it is "a font with only 14 glyphs in it". This number changes every time I select another element, according to the length of the text inside the element. Usually, I see there the actual name of the font-family used to render the element. I do not understand why I see a "." on this particular case instead.

Comment: In that case, got a URL for other people to look at, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a public URL that you can look at. I will try to think about whether I can create a public page to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rendered fonts" section works the following way.

When you inspect an element in the page, e.g. a span with some text, the Chrome DevTools will analyze the text inside the selected node. For every character of the text inside selected node, it will figure out which font was used to render that character.

This information will be summed up in the "Rendered Fonts" section, in a format " - ".

In your specific example, this means that 14 characters of text were rendered using a font with name ".".

This kind of fonts are usually webfonts which for some reason do not setup a correct name in their description.